# Recoding longitudinal variables in R

Tags: r

I have a longitudinal data frame `prueba` that follows different units (variable `LA`) over time (variables `time`and `year`). The first 25 observations have the following structure.

```
> head(prueba, 25)
                     LA month year entry exit total homes
1  Barking and Dagenham    10 2010     2    0     2    NA
2  Barking and Dagenham    11 2010     3    0     3    NA
3  Barking and Dagenham    12 2010     3    0     3    15
4  Barking and Dagenham     1 2011     6    0     6    NA
5  Barking and Dagenham     2 2011     1    0     1    NA
6  Barking and Dagenham     3 2011     2    0     2    NA
7  Barking and Dagenham     4 2011     1    0     1    NA
8  Barking and Dagenham    10 2011     1    0     1    NA
9  Barking and Dagenham    11 2011     1    0     1    NA
10 Barking and Dagenham     1 2012     1    0     1    NA
11 Barking and Dagenham     9 2012     1    0     1    NA
12 Barking and Dagenham     6 2013     2    0     2    NA
13 Barking and Dagenham     1 2014     0    1    -1    NA
14 Barking and Dagenham    12 2014     0    1    -1    NA
15 Barking and Dagenham     3 2015     1    1     0    NA
16 Barking and Dagenham    11 2015     1    1     0    NA
17 Barking and Dagenham    12 2015     1    0     1    NA
18               Barnet    11 2010    24    0    24    NA
19               Barnet    12 2010    28    0    28    86
20               Barnet     1 2011    28    0    28    NA
21               Barnet     2 2011     6    0     6    NA
22               Barnet     3 2011     1    0     1    NA
23               Barnet     4 2011     1    0     1    NA
24               Barnet     7 2011     2    0     2    NA
25               Barnet     8 2011     1    0     1    NA
```

My aim is to recode the `homes` variable by assigning the values that are not missing to the observations where `month == "2"` and  `year == "2011"`. In case there are not observations for these values of `month`and `year`, the relabelled observations would be those corresponding to `month == "1"`and `year == "2011"`. Ideally, the expected output would be something like this:

```
> head(prueba, 25)
                     LA month year entry exit total homes
1  Barking and Dagenham    10 2010     2    0     2    NA
2  Barking and Dagenham    11 2010     3    0     3    NA
3  Barking and Dagenham    12 2010     3    0     3    NA
4  Barking and Dagenham     1 2011     6    0     6    NA
5  Barking and Dagenham     2 2011     1    0     1    15
6  Barking and Dagenham     3 2011     2    0     2    NA
7  Barking and Dagenham     4 2011     1    0     1    NA
8  Barking and Dagenham    10 2011     1    0     1    NA
9  Barking and Dagenham    11 2011     1    0     1    NA
10 Barking and Dagenham     1 2012     1    0     1    NA
11 Barking and Dagenham     9 2012     1    0     1    NA
12 Barking and Dagenham     6 2013     2    0     2    NA
13 Barking and Dagenham     1 2014     0    1    -1    NA
14 Barking and Dagenham    12 2014     0    1    -1    NA
15 Barking and Dagenham     3 2015     1    1     0    NA
16 Barking and Dagenham    11 2015     1    1     0    NA
17 Barking and Dagenham    12 2015     1    0     1    NA
18               Barnet    11 2010    24    0    24    NA
19               Barnet    12 2010    28    0    28    NA
20               Barnet     1 2011    28    0    28    NA
21               Barnet     2 2011     6    0     6    86
22               Barnet     3 2011     1    0     1    NA
23               Barnet     4 2011     1    0     1    NA
24               Barnet     7 2011     2    0     2    NA
25               Barnet     8 2011     1    0     1    NA
```

I have approached this by using `data.table` on the following basis:

```
test = data.table(prueba)
setkey(test, LA)
test$homes =test[, .SD[, ifelse(year == "2011" & month == "2", !is.na(homes), homes)], by=LA]
```

But it is not yielding the expected output.

```
> head(test, 25)
                      LA month year entry exit total homes
 1: Barking and Dagenham    10 2010     2    0     2    NA
 2: Barking and Dagenham    11 2010     3    0     3    NA
 3: Barking and Dagenham    12 2010     3    0     3    15
 4: Barking and Dagenham     1 2011     6    0     6    NA
 5: Barking and Dagenham     2 2011     1    0     1    NA
 6: Barking and Dagenham     3 2011     2    0     2    NA
 7: Barking and Dagenham     4 2011     1    0     1    NA
 8: Barking and Dagenham    10 2011     1    0     1    NA
 9: Barking and Dagenham    11 2011     1    0     1    NA
10: Barking and Dagenham     1 2012     1    0     1    NA
11: Barking and Dagenham     9 2012     1    0     1    NA
12: Barking and Dagenham     6 2013     2    0     2    NA
13: Barking and Dagenham     1 2014     0    1    -1    NA
14: Barking and Dagenham    12 2014     0    1    -1    NA
15: Barking and Dagenham     3 2015     1    1     0    NA
16: Barking and Dagenham    11 2015     1    1     0    NA
17: Barking and Dagenham    12 2015     1    0     1    NA
18:               Barnet    11 2010    24    0    24    NA
19:               Barnet    12 2010    28    0    28    86
20:               Barnet     1 2011    28    0    28    NA
21:               Barnet     2 2011     6    0     6    NA
22:               Barnet     3 2011     1    0     1    NA
23:               Barnet     4 2011     1    0     1    NA
24:               Barnet     7 2011     2    0     2    NA
25:               Barnet     8 2011     1    0     1    NA
                      LA month year entry exit total homes
```

I would be grateful if someone can suggest an alternative approach to this -  not necessarily wit `data.table`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
dfs <- data.frame(df %>% 
                  group_by(LA) %>% 
                  summarise(Homes = sum(homes, na.rm = T)) %>%
                  inner_join(.,df, by = 'LA') %>% 
                  mutate(Homes = ifelse(month == 2 & year == 2011, Homes, NA)))
```

This should do the trick, and using the `dplyr` package has a lot of speed as opposed to doing it iteratively (e.g. `for` or `while`).

Comment: Many thanks @akash87; it still does not work, it creates `Homes` a variable full of `NA`s.

Comment: @Edu There was a misplaced parenthesis. It has been corrected. Also did you only want the data frame withouth the NAs?

Comment: Thanks again @akash87. It still does not work. I think in your `inner_join()` there should be a `by` argument. I don´t mind about the `NA`s. My main goal is just to recode those observations corresponding to the month and year indicated. `NA`s can be transformed later on.

Comment: @Edu Based on the data you presented I did not have a problem. I did include the `by` statement.

Comment: Once I added the argument `by` it created `Homes` recoded as I wanted. Certainly it works quicker than `data.table`. Many thanks for your help @akash87.