# R data.table: output turning into different values when recoding variables

Tags: r, data.table

Note: This post is related to another post ([Recoding longitudinal variables in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37834000/recoding-longitudinal-variables-in-r))

I have a `data.table` and I want to recode the values of a variable (`homes`) conditioned to the values of other variables. Essentially I want the observation corresponding to `month == "1"` and `year == "2011"`to be the value in `month == "12"` and `year == "2010"`. The `data.table` looks like this:

```
  > head(test,25)
                      LA month year entry exit total homes
 1: Barking and Dagenham    10 2010     2    0     2    NA
 2: Barking and Dagenham    11 2010     3    0     3    NA
 3: Barking and Dagenham    12 2010     3    0     3    15
 4: Barking and Dagenham     1 2011     6    0     6    NA
 5: Barking and Dagenham     2 2011     1    0     1    NA
 6: Barking and Dagenham     3 2011     2    0     2    NA
 7: Barking and Dagenham     4 2011     1    0     1    NA
 8: Barking and Dagenham    10 2011     1    0     1    NA
 9: Barking and Dagenham    11 2011     1    0     1    NA
10: Barking and Dagenham     1 2012     1    0     1    NA
11: Barking and Dagenham     9 2012     1    0     1    NA
12: Barking and Dagenham     6 2013     2    0     2    NA
13: Barking and Dagenham     1 2014     0    1    -1    NA
14: Barking and Dagenham    12 2014     0    1    -1    NA
15: Barking and Dagenham     3 2015     1    1     0    NA
16: Barking and Dagenham    11 2015     1    1     0    NA
17: Barking and Dagenham    12 2015     1    0     1    NA
18:               Barnet    11 2010    24    0    24    NA
19:               Barnet    12 2010    28    0    28    86
20:               Barnet     1 2011    28    0    28    NA
21:               Barnet     2 2011     6    0     6    NA
22:               Barnet     3 2011     1    0     1    NA
23:               Barnet     4 2011     1    0     1    NA
24:               Barnet     7 2011     2    0     2    NA
25:               Barnet     8 2011     1    0     1    NA
                      LA month year entry exit total homes
```

The structure of this `data.table`is as follows:

```
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  4664 obs. of  7 variables:
 $ LA   : Factor w/ 151 levels "Barking and Dagenham",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ month: int  10 11 12 1 2 3 4 10 11 1 ...
 $ year : int  2010 2010 2010 2011 2011 2011 2011 2011 2011 2012 ...
 $ entry: int  2 3 3 6 1 2 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ exit : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ total: int  2 3 3 6 1 2 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ homes: int  NA NA 15 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
```

In order to recode `homes` I create a new variable `homes.1`. I use the following `data.table` functions:

```
 test = test[year== "2011" & month == "1", homes.1 := as.numeric(!is.na(homes)), by = LA]

test[, homes.1 := ifelse(!is.na(homes.1),
                         test[month == "12" & year == "2010",homes],
                         homes.1), by=LA]
```

I obtain partially what I want. The variable homes.1 gets recoded but with different values than the ones corresponding to variable homes. The first 25 observations of `test` look:

```
LA month year entry exit total homes homes.1
 1: Barking and Dagenham    10 2010     2    0     2    NA      NA
 2: Barking and Dagenham    11 2010     3    0     3    NA      NA
 3: Barking and Dagenham    12 2010     3    0     3    15      NA
 4: Barking and Dagenham     1 2011     6    0     6    NA      46
 5: Barking and Dagenham     2 2011     1    0     1    NA      NA
 6: Barking and Dagenham     3 2011     2    0     2    NA      NA
 7: Barking and Dagenham     4 2011     1    0     1    NA      NA
 8: Barking and Dagenham    10 2011     1    0     1    NA      NA
 9: Barking and Dagenham    11 2011     1    0     1    NA      NA
10: Barking and Dagenham     1 2012     1    0     1    NA      NA
11: Barking and Dagenham     9 2012     1    0     1    NA      NA
12: Barking and Dagenham     6 2013     2    0     2    NA      NA
13: Barking and Dagenham     1 2014     0    1    -1    NA      NA
14: Barking and Dagenham    12 2014     0    1    -1    NA      NA
15: Barking and Dagenham     3 2015     1    1     0    NA      NA
16: Barking and Dagenham    11 2015     1    1     0    NA      NA
17: Barking and Dagenham    12 2015     1    0     1    NA      NA
18:               Barnet    11 2010    24    0    24    NA      NA
19:               Barnet    12 2010    28    0    28    86      NA
20:               Barnet     1 2011    28    0    28    NA      55
21:               Barnet     2 2011     6    0     6    NA      NA
22:               Barnet     3 2011     1    0     1    NA      NA
23:               Barnet     4 2011     1    0     1    NA      NA
24:               Barnet     7 2011     2    0     2    NA      NA
25:               Barnet     8 2011     1    0     1    NA      NA
                      LA month year entry exit total homes homes.1
```

Likewise, the structure of `test` with homes.1 is:

```
> str(test)
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  4664 obs. of  8 variables:
 $ LA     : Factor w/ 151 levels "Barking and Dagenham",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ month  : int  10 11 12 1 2 3 4 10 11 1 ...
 $ year   : int  2010 2010 2010 2011 2011 2011 2011 2011 2011 2012 ...
 $ entry  : int  2 3 3 6 1 2 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ exit   : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ total  : int  2 3 3 6 1 2 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ homes  : int  NA NA 15 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ homes.1: num  NA NA NA 46 NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

I wonder why it is not recoding properly the observations of `homes.1` according to `homes` values. The expected output should look like:

```
       LA month year entry exit total homes homes.1
 1: Barking and Dagenham    10 2010     2    0     2    NA      NA
 2: Barking and Dagenham    11 2010     3    0     3    NA      NA
 3: Barking and Dagenham    12 2010     3    0     3    15      NA
 4: Barking and Dagenham     1 2011     6    0     6    NA      15
 5: Barking and Dagenham     2 2011     1    0     1    NA      NA
 6: Barking and Dagenham     3 2011     2    0     2    NA      NA
 7: Barking and Dagenham     4 2011     1    0     1    NA      NA
 8: Barking and Dagenham    10 2011     1    0     1    NA      NA
 9: Barking and Dagenham    11 2011     1    0     1    NA      NA
10: Barking and Dagenham     1 2012     1    0     1    NA      NA
11: Barking and Dagenham     9 2012     1    0     1    NA      NA
12: Barking and Dagenham     6 2013     2    0     2    NA      NA
13: Barking and Dagenham     1 2014     0    1    -1    NA      NA
14: Barking and Dagenham    12 2014     0    1    -1    NA      NA
15: Barking and Dagenham     3 2015     1    1     0    NA      NA
16: Barking and Dagenham    11 2015     1    1     0    NA      NA
17: Barking and Dagenham    12 2015     1    0     1    NA      NA
18:               Barnet    11 2010    24    0    24    NA      NA
19:               Barnet    12 2010    28    0    28    86      NA
20:               Barnet     1 2011    28    0    28    NA      86
21:               Barnet     2 2011     6    0     6    NA      NA
22:               Barnet     3 2011     1    0     1    NA      NA
23:               Barnet     4 2011     1    0     1    NA      NA
24:               Barnet     7 2011     2    0     2    NA      NA
25:               Barnet     8 2011     1    0     1    NA      NA
                      LA month year entry exit total homes homes.1
```

Comment: I think that's cause of the conditions you're giving to the `data.table` function. You'll need to create the `homes.1` variable first.

Comment: It would help if you dput the example data. My guess is that you can do a merge-assign sort of thing

Comment: you should include a code to create dataset to make your question reproducible

Answer (score 1):

You get 0 because for the rows where `year== "2011" & month == "1"` the expression `is.na(homes)` returns `TRUE`, so when you do `!is.na(homes)` it returns `FALSE`.
Then, since you created your `homes.1` variable coercing logical values to numeric, it automatically translates `TRUE` to `1` and `FALSE` to `0`.

This is not necessarily a problem, however. You can replace these `0` values with another statement which should look like this:

```
test[, homes.1 := ifelse(!is.na(homes.1),
                  test[month == "12" & year == "2010",homes],
                  homes.1),
       by=LA]
```

Could you tell me if this works? If it does, then you can simply merge the two columns.

Comment: I think that won't work as written, since `.SD` is "locked"/cannot be edited.

Comment: I edited my comment: could it work like that? Without the data it's hard to say anything..

Comment: Hm, yeah, something like that might work. Yeah, we'll have to wait until someone provides the OP's data in a reproducible form before we can be sure, I guess.

Comment: Thanks @hellter and @Frank.  It does not work since it does not find `homes.1`. It gives the following error. `Error in ifelse(!is.na(homes.1), test[month == "12" & year == "2010",  : 
  object 'homes.1' not found`

Comment: You should run the code **after** running your own code, where you create the `homes.1` variable just like in the question..

Comment: Thanks @hellter. It does what I am after but it gets a weird result. It writes different numbers. Example with the first group of LA` > head(test, 25)
                      LA month year entry exit total homes homes.1
 1: Barking and Dagenham    10 2010     2    0     2    NA      NA
 2: Barking and Dagenham    11 2010     3    0     3    NA      NA
 3: Barking and Dagenham    12 2010     3    0     3    15      NA
 4: Barking and Dagenham     1 2011     6    0     6    NA      46
 5: Barking and Dagenham     2 2011     1    0     1    NA      NA`

Comment: I'm sorry but what without any formatting I can't understand what you just wrote.. Edit your question putting this information in a proper table, indicating what's the bug and what you would like the output to be like.

Comment: @hellter, many thanks. I edited the question so that I hope is more clarifying. Could the change in the values be referred to the type different types of variables considered? (e.g. `homes.1` `as numeric` vs `homes` `as.integer`)

Comment: I can't see any edits in your question.. btw the distinction between integer and numeric shouldn't lead to mistakes in your case as long as numeric values don't have commas.